# Get the total amount of pages from Win32_PrintJob

Tags: c#, .net, windows, printing, wmi

The Win32_PrintJob WMI class has lots of properties. (see: [Win32_PrintJob on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

I have a small .NET application that poles the printing jobs and displays the jobs' information.

The `TotalPages` propery gives the amount of pages sent. But that figure DOESN'T take into account the number of copies requested by the user. So, if a user wants to print 5 copies of a two page document, the value of `TotalPages` will be 2, not 10.

How can i get the number of copies for a printing job, or get the total amount of pages to be printed (number of copies times number of pages in the job)?

Thanks

Comment: There is no solution for this.  Printer drivers often ask the printer with a proprietary command to generate the copies instead of spooling the same document repeatedly.  Very efficient but Windows doesn't know what these custom drivers do.  The printer manufacturer often has some kind of management software.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem with Win32_PrintJob (TotalPages/PagesPrinted doesn't take into account number of copies). I solved it by combining WMI with Win api.

Number of copies can be retrieved from [DEVMODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183565%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure (dmCopies) which is part of [JOB_INFO_2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145020%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure.

So you call GetJob with Level=2 and you will get JOB_INFO_2 instance. From there, it's piece of cake, just little bit of marshaling :).

Hope this helps.

Cheers,

Lukas

Comment: I've searching about how to use that in c# and I didn't found anything, can I do it in c#???, help me with a example

Comment: I am facing the same problem, would you mind show your code?

Comment: can you provide the vbscript for the combining things (WMI and WinAPI) just as you mentioned @LukasTines? I need to obtain the current printerjob including the 'number of copies' but fails.