# C# printing how to get copy count

Tags: c#, printing, copy, spooler, print-spooler-api

I am trying to make a printing manangement server. I have 1 printer which is shared with 4 other people.

```
try
{
    string PrinterJobs = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob";
    ManagementObjectSearcher FindPrintJobs =
              new ManagementObjectSearcher(PrinterJobs);
    ManagementObjectCollection prntJobCollection = FindPrintJobs.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject prntJob in prntJobCollection)
    {
        string jobName = prntJob.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();
        string documentName = prntJob.Properties["Document"].Value.ToString();
      string nbcopie = prntJob.Properties["TotalPages"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

But i need to get number of copies of each printjob( eg user2 make 3copy of the same print job)

I need to see copy count before printing. 
please help me

Comment: Possible guidance [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256737/get-the-total-amount-of-pages-from-win32-printjob).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082445/setjob-method-always-returns-122 get Interop methods from this link. After this get JOB_INFO_2.DEVMODE.dmCopies

Comment: its only exist in C++?

Comment: guys please formulate an answer or mark as duplicate. This question is used as another reference for duplicate,  and still doesn't have an answer provided/ accepted